# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Project Management Stack Exchange](http://pm.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://pm.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How can we stop developers from working on stories that are not planned into the current sprint?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12091/how-can-we-stop-developers-from-working-on-stories-that-are-not-planned-into-the)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Would Scrum & Kanban work for a small organisation with several "projects"](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/would-scrum-kanban-work-for-a-small-organisation-with-several-projects)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What are the benefits of estimating hours during the task breakdown?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12009/what-are-the-benefits-of-estimating-hours-during-the-task-breakdown)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What to do when someone says "that is not an acceptable solution"?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12094/what-to-do-when-someone-says-that-is-not-an-acceptable-solution)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Agile Development and when to deliver](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12102/agile-development-and-when-to-deliver)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can you Gate each Agile Sprint to provide comfort to Stakeholders in Waterfall?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12059/can-you-gate-each-agile-sprint-to-provide-comfort-to-stakeholders-in-waterfall)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How should we assess "Build vs. Buy" for an ERP System?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/how-should-we-assess-build-vs-buy-for-an-erp-system)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How does one integrate reward systems at an individual level into an Agile landscape, without damaging team cohesion?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/how-does-one-integrate-reward-systems-at-an-individual-level-into-an-agile-lands)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to communicate a delay to a client when team member is ill?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12117/how-to-communicate-a-delay-to-a-client-when-team-member-is-ill)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In JIRA, when I moved issues from one project to another, they don't show up in Agile view, but show up in project view](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/11951/in-jira-when-i-moved-issues-from-one-project-to-another-they-dont-show-up-in)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---